# Xcode crashed when I open the main.storyboard, no matter if it's a new project or not

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've searched on google for some time and can't find the answer to this problem of mine.

When I try to open the main.storyboard of any swift project, my xcode crashes, I can access the source code and all, just not the interface builder.

I get the error which can be seen in the pastebin link:
http://pastebin.com/URgBuPkV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this looks like a bug in your Xcode.

I would recommend to simply de-install and then re-install Xcode.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Well it worked, though I did it yesterday as well, for some reason it works today... mbe today is a good day? :) thx for the response!